# Simple, lightweight alternatives to FoxTab

Tags: firefox, firefox-extensions

I've always liked how Google Chrome's new tab-page looks, presenting you with thumbnails of the most used web sites and lists your recently closed tabs. I understand FoxTab does this, but it's a bit sluggish and slow for just presenting thumbnails of website you visit regularly.

Are there any lightweight, less sluggish alternatives to FoxTab out there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/super-start/
This addon should suffice if you're okay with not having recently closed tabs.